# How to calculate the individual sums of multiple columns in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle 11gR2 on windows 7 client. I have the following sample table:

```
Yr     Mnth       Region    City            Handled_Package     Expected_Missing_Package      Actual_Missing_Package

2012   November   Western   San Fransisco   200                 10                            5
2012   November   Western   Los Angeles     400                 20                            15
2012   November   Eastern   New York        300                 15                            20
2012   November   Western   Seattle         100                 5                             7
2012   November   Eastern   Philadelphia    200                 10                            12
2012   November   MidWest   Chicago         300                 15                            15

2012   December   MidWest   Detroit         50                  3                             2
2012   December   Western   Los Angeles     300                 15                            19
2012   December   Eastern   New York        400                 20                            16
2012   December   Eastern   Philadelphia    150                 8                             6
2012   December   MidWest   Chicago         200                 10                            10

2013   January    Eastern   New York        200                 10                            9
2013   January    MidWest   Chicago         100                 5                             7
2013   January    Western   San Fransisco   500                 25                            22
2013   January    Western   Los Angeles     200                 10                            8
2013   January    Europe    London          500                 25                            27
2013   January    Europe    Paris           400                 20                            23

2013   Februray   Europe    London          200                 10                            9
2013   Februray   Eastern   Philadelphia    300                 15                            13
2013   Februray   Eastern   NY              400                 20                            18
2013   February   Western   San Fransisco   400                 20                            12
2013   Februray   Western   LA              200                 10                            8
2013   Februray   MidWest   Detroit         300                 15                            13
```

I want to make a view out of it which will store the sums of all NUMBER columns (i.e. Handled_Package, Expected_Missing_Package, Actual_Missing_Package)
for each month of a year for each location. I.e. the output should look like the following:

```
Yr      Mnth        Region      Handled_Package   Expected_Missing_Package  Actual_Missing_Package

2012    November    Eastern     500               25                        32
2012    November    Europe      0                 0                         0
2012    November    MidWest     300               15                        15
2012    November    Western     700               35                        27

2012    December    Eastern     250               13                        12
2012    November    Europe      0                 0                         0
2012    December    MidWest     550               28                        22
2012    December    Western     300               15                        19

2013    January     Eastern     200               10                        9
2013    January     Europe      900               45                        50
2013    January     MidWest     100               5                         7
2013    January     Western     700               35                        30

2013    February    Eastern     700               35                        31
2013    February    Europe      200               10                        9
2013    February    MidWest     300               15                        13
2013    February    Western     600               30                        20
```

How would I do that? For your convenience here are the create and insert scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    Yr                         VARCHAR2(5),
    Mnth                       VARCHAR2(50),
    Region                     VARCHAR2(50), 
    CITY                       VARCHAR2(50),              
    Handled_Package            NUMBER,        
    Expected_Missing_Package   NUMBER,    
    Actual_Missing_Package     NUMBER
);



Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'November', 'Western', 'San Fransisco', 200, 10, 5);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'November', 'Western', 'Los Angeles', 400, 20, 15);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'November', 'Eastern', 'New York', 300, 15, 20);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'November', 'Western', 'Seattle', 100, 5, 7);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'November', 'Eastern', 'Philadelphia', 200, 10, 12);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'November', 'MidWest', 'Chicago', 300, 15, 15);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'December', 'MidWest', 'Detroit', 50, 3, 2);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'December', 'Western', 'Los Angeles', 300, 15, 19);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'December', 'Eastern', 'New York', 400, 20, 16);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'December', 'Eastern', 'Philadelphia', 150, 8, 6);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2012', 'December', 'MidWest', 'Chicago', 200, 10, 10);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'January', 'Eastern', 'New York', 200, 10, 9);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'January', 'MidWest', 'Chicagio', 100, 5, 7);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'January', 'Western', 'San Fransisco', 500, 25, 22);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'January', 'Western', 'Los Angeles', 200, 10, 8);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'January', 'Europe', 'London', 500, 25, 27);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'January', 'Europe', 'Paris', 400, 20, 23);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'Februray', 'Europe', 'London', 200, 10, 9);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'Februray', 'Eastern', 'Philadelphia', 300, 15, 13);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'Februray', 'Eastern', 'NY', 400, 20, 18);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'Februray', 'Western', 'San Fransisco', 400, 20, 12);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'Februray', 'Western', 'LA', 200, 10, 8);

Insert into TEST (YR, MNTH, REGION, CITY, HANDLED_PACKAGE, EXPECTED_MISSING_PACKAGE, ACTUAL_MISSING_PACKAGE)
Values ('2013', 'Februray', 'MidWest', 'Detroit', 300, 15, 13);

COMMIT;
```

Will appreciate any help  or suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Oops, my bad, sorry! What I really wanted is a full-list of "Regions" for every month, as shown in the updated output section. E.g. Europe should be added for the month of November and December whose NUMBER columns should be zero. Also how would I use analytic function instead of simple group by clause here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT Yr,Mnth,Region,
   SUM(Handled_Package) Handled_Package,
   SUM(Expected_Missing_Package) Expected_Missing_Package,
   SUM(Actual_Missing_Package) Actual_Missing_Package
FROM TEST
GROUP BY Yr,Mnth,Region
ORDER BY Yr,Mnth,Region
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/812f6/2).

Your update complicates things somewhat, this joins in non existing regions as zero rows and uses `OVER (PARTITION BY)` instead of `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Yr,r.Mnth,r.Region,
   COALESCE(SUM(t.Handled_Package)
   OVER (PARTITION BY r.Yr,r.Mnth,r.Region), 0) Handled_Package,
   COALESCE(SUM(t.Expected_Missing_Package) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY r.Yr,r.Mnth,r.Region), 0) Expected_Missing_Package,
   COALESCE(SUM(t.Actual_Missing_Package) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY r.Yr,r.Mnth,r.Region), 0) Actual_Missing_Package 
FROM TEST t
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT t1.Region,t2.Yr,t2.Mnth FROM TEST t1 CROSS JOIN TEST t2
) r
ON t.Yr = r.Yr AND t.Mnth=r.Mnth AND t.Region=r.Region
ORDER BY r.Yr,r.Mnth,r.Region
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/087b8/3)

The latter can probably be simplified, I must admit Oracle's analytic functions aren't my specialty :)